# Including SUM on SQL Inner Join query

Tags: sql, sum, inner-join

I have two tables, movies and reservations. I'm trying to figure out how to get my query to return only unique movie ids/titles and sum the total number of tickets listed in a table with multiple entries per movie.
Below is what I'm trying, with no luck. What am I missing here?

```
SELECT movies.id AS id, movies.title AS title, SUM(reservations.number_of_tickets) AS sold_tickets
FROM reservations
INNER JOIN movies ON reservations.movie_id = movies.id
ORDER BY sold_tickets DESC, id
```

When I run the query without trying SUM, I almost get what I want, except the query has multiple rows for the same movies:

```
SELECT movies.id AS id, movies.title AS title, reservations.number_of_tickets AS sold_tickets
FROM reservations
INNER JOIN movies ON reservations.movie_id = movies.id
ORDER BY sold_tickets DESC, id
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT m.id, m.title, SUM(r.number_of_tickets) AS sold_tickets
FROM movies m INNER JOIN
     reservations r 
     ON r.movie_id = m.id
GROUP BY m.id, m.title
ORDER BY sold_tickets DESC, id;
```

Notes:

- Learn to use subqueries.
- There is no need to rename a column to the same name.  So `movies.id` is already called `id` in the result set.
- I swapped the order of the `join`s.  I do so you can turn the `INNER JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN` if you want movies with no reservations.